# How to replace single slash "\" to "\\\" in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to replace single slash to triple slash in Objective-C. I'm unable to do conversion.

Example:

```
NSString *string = "pW`-={}|[]456\";

string =  [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\" withString:@"\"];
```

I want to output: pW`-={}|[]456\\

Comment: try this string  = `[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\" withString:@"\'"];`

Comment: @chirag90 It's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every back-slash in Objective-C string literal should be presented with two back-slashes (first one is escaping back-slash), otherwise it will not even compile, so

If you want convert this

```
pW`-={}|[]456\
```

into this

```
pW`-={}|[]456\\\
```

it needs to call

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\\\"];
```

if vice-versa, then correspondingly

```
string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
```